# Remote JIRA issues creation

Tags: jira

I need to link JIRA issues to each other from my C# utility.

I cannot use REST API because my JIRA's version is 4.4 and I'm not able to upgrade.

Comment: What have you looked into or tried so far?

Comment: I tried to make it with SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky that, since there's no addLink() method in the SOAP method you have to use. I did it using a shell script to call the URL directly but you will need to know the JIRA issue ids not just the issue keys. I think this worked with JIRA 4.4 but not 5.x

~Matt

p.s. the code formatter in this editor is terrible!

```
#
# Add links to JIRA issues
#
# Matt Doar
# CustomWare
# 
# usage: create_links.sh issue_id issue_key
# where the issue_id is the unique id for a JIRA issue, not it's issue key.
# You can see the issue id in the XML view of an issue.
# and issue_key is the other issue to be linked to.

USERNAME=admin
PASSWORD=secret
SERVER_URL="http://localhost:8080"

DASHBOARD_PAGE_URL=$SERVER_URL/secure/Dashboard.jspa
COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION=jiracoookie

# Get the authentication cookie
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --cookie-jar $COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION -sS --output /dev/null $DASHBOARD_PAGE_URL

issueid=$1
issuekey=$2
#echo "Linking issue: $issueid and $issuekey"
curl --cookie $COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION --header "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -sS --output /dev/null -d "id=$issueid" -d "linkDesc=relates to" -d "linkKey=$issuekey" "$SERVER_URL/secure/LinkExistingIssue.jspa"

rm -f $COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION
```

Comment: I am using WebRequest (.NET), there is an error when using `=` separator in headers. Using `:` instead.